# Excel VBA loop through all hyperlinks in outlook html and copy to excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Hi I have written some vba code to loop through all emails in a folder , but I am struggling to find a way to look for a hyperlink. copy the hyperlink to the next empty row in column A. copy the text beneath the hyperlink to Column B. Then look for next hyperlink and repeat process. At present my code copies everything from the email and the hyperlinks are showing actual link not the visible wording.

[image]

Code

```
Option Explicit
Sub Get_Google_Alerts_From_Emails()
Sheet1.Select
ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ObjOutlook As Object
Dim MyNamespace As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long
Dim abody() As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim k
Dim x
Dim google_text As String

Dim strPattern As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Dim regEx As New RegExp
strPattern = "\s+"
strReplace = " "
x = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Set ObjOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

Set MyNamespace = ObjOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
k = MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("_Google_Alerts").Items.Count
For i = k To 1 Step -1
On Error GoTo vend
strSubject = MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("_Google_Alerts").Items(i).Subject

If strSubject Like "*Google*" Then GoTo google:

GoTo notfound

google:
abody = Split(MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("_Google_Alerts").Items(i).Body, vbCrLf)

For j = 0 To UBound(abody)
On Error GoTo error_google
If Len(abody(j)) > 1 Then
With regEx
.Pattern = "(https?[:]//([0-9a-z=\?:/\.&-^!#$;_])*)"
.Global = False
.IgnoreCase = True
End With

If regEx.Test(abody(j)) Then
google_text = regEx.Replace(abody(j), strReplace)
End If
With objRegex
.Pattern = "[A-Z]+"
.Global = True
.IgnoreCase = False
If .Test(abody(j)) Then
x = x + 1
Sheet1.Range("A" & x) = google_text
Sheet1.Range("C" & x) = strSubject
Else

End If
End With
End If
error_google:
Next j
MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("_Google_Alerts").Items(i).Move MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("_Google_Alerts_Complete")
GoTo comp
notfound:
comp:
Next i
vend:
Set ObjOutlook = Nothing
Set MyNamespace = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest to create one 'Main' procedure which calls subs and functions that execute the various steps of your plan. In this way you would have small parts of code which you can ask questions about if they don't perform as required. The conglomerate you publish above takes too much time to analyse.

Comment: Can you share your regex demo link?

Answer (score 0):

> At present my code copies everything from the email and the hyperlinks are showing actual link not the visible wording.

Here is a very basic example to achieve what you want. I am using `Debug.Print` to show the data. Feel free to amend it to move it to Excel. I am running this code from Excel.

```
Option Explicit

Const olMail As Integer = 43

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim MyNamespace As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim olkMsg As Object
    Dim objWordDocument As Object
    Dim objWordApp As Object
    Dim objHyperlinks As Object
    Dim objHyperlink As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MyNamespace = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    '~~> Let the user select the folder
    Set objFolder = MyNamespace.PickFolder

    '~~> Loop through the emails in that folder
    For Each olkMsg In objFolder.Items
        '~~> Check if it is an email
        If olkMsg.Class = olMail Then
            '~~> Get the word inspector
            Set objWordDocument = olkMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor
            Set objWordApp = objWordDocument.Application
            Set objHyperlinks = objWordDocument.Hyperlinks

            If objHyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
               For Each objHyperlink In objHyperlinks
                   Debug.Print objHyperlink.Address '<~~ Address
                   Debug.Print objHyperlink.TextToDisplay '<~~ Display text
               Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code , is there a way to copy the text that is after each hyperlink as the emails are from google alerts so they have the link , then a brief description of the news story contained in the link. I wastrying to copy this text to the next column where the hyperlink is. so column A next empty row hyperlink , then text in column B

Comment: Is it possible to see a screenshot of one such email?

Comment: I was also trying to find a way to ignore links if they contain certain generic text but my attempt from your code is not working If objHyperlink.TextToDisplay = "Flag as irrelevant" Then GoTo junk
               If objHyperlink.TextToDisplay = "See more results" Then GoTo junk
               If objHyperlink.TextToDisplay = "Edit this alert" Then GoTo junk
               If objHyperlink.TextToDisplay = "View all your alerts" Then GoTo junk
               If objHyperlink.TextToDisplay = "Send Feedback" Then GoTo junk

Comment: `If instr(1,objHyperlink.TextToDisplay,"Sometext",vbtextcompare) = 0 then`

Comment: Also do not use so many `GoTo` unnecessarily :) Restructure your code

Comment: how do I add a screenshot please

Comment: upload it in say wikisend.com and share the link here. I will put that in your question

Comment: One way I can think is to parse the HTMLBody of the email. I am at office. will try and look at it in the evening when i get back home...

Comment: Thanks for looking at this for me. I have spent all week trying to find a solution

Comment: Can you forward that email to `forstackoverflowexamples@gmail.com`

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I need some help with my outlook-vba script. I've contacted you because I found you as the best person who can help me. My link is https://superuser.com/questions/1397111/ms-outlook-vba-script-automatic-print-original-email-when-it-gets-undelivered